# Trying to update all columns with the result of the subquery

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-update

I'm very new to SQL and I'm trying to do the following:

```
update the salary of employees with their department avg salary.
```

I'm trying the SQL commands [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/edea8/3).

The command I'm trying is :

```
update emp set sal = select avg(sal) from emp;
```

but I'm getting an error like this:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression : update emp set sal = select avg(sal) from emp
```

where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update emp 
set sal = (SELECT av FROM (SELECT AVG(sal) av FROM emp) s) 
from emp;
```

Comment: did it worked? first you cannot update directly the table if the value came from select. second, you need to wrap the statement with subquery as it returns a value.

Answer (score 1):

what you have tried is correct only...in general sub query should kept inside the brackets just try this one:`update emp set sal = (select avg(sal) from emp);`

ref this:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/edea8/4